# Knockout Template Binding with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am trying to use jQuery ListView control inside the Knockout Template but the binding fails and does not work as expected. Here is the code:

```
 <div data-bind="template: { name: 'myItem', foreach: lineItems }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="myItem">    
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img style="width:50px; height:50px;" data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }">
                 <h2>Broken Bells</h2>   
            </a>
             </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't see a reason why knockout would interfere with jQueryUI; so if the DOM is rendered as expected, you've probably got a jquery issue; if not you've probably got a knockout issue.

Comment: @john doe 
for each lineItems, you'll have sturcture like this 
<div>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<div>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="template: { name: 'myItem', foreach: lineItems }"></ul>
</div>

<script type="text/html" id="myItem">    
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img style="width:50px; height:50px;" data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl }">
            <h2>Broken Bells</h2>   
        </a>
    </li>
</script>
```